# How to load a report FastReports totally in runtime?

Tags: delphi, fastreport

How to load a report FastReports totally in runtime?

I would like to load and run my reports all at runtime. I designed the reports in the FastReports editor, saved the project file and now I need to load them at runtime.

Everything will be created at runtime.
frxReport
frxDBDataset
frxPDFExport

I set up the coding, however there is an error in PrepareReport, because FastReports looks for the frxDBDataSet1 linked in the report and cannot find it.

I'm not sure how to do this step.

My method looks like this:

```pascal
procedure TServerReports.Catalogo;
var
  LReport    : TfrxReport;
  LPDF       : TfrxPDFExport;
  LDataSet   : TfrxDBDataset;
  LFileName  : string;
begin
  try
    LReport          := TfrxReport.Create(nil);

    LDataSet         := TfrxDBDataset.Create(nil);
    LDataSet.DataSet := Query;

    LPDF             := TfrxPDFExport.Create(nil);

    LReport.DataSets.Add(LDataSet);
    LReport.LoadFromFile(Format('%s\%s', [TConfig.DirFastReports, 'Catalogo_02.fr3']));

    LReport.DataSet := LDataSet;

    LFileName := Format('%s\Catalogo%s.pdf', [TConfig.DirSaveReports, FormatDateTime('DDMMYYYhhmmss', Now)]);

    LReport.FileName                := LFileName;
    LReport.PrepareReport(); //Error because frxDBDataSet1
    LReport.ShowProgress            := False;
    LReport.PrintOptions.ShowDialog := False;

    LPDF.ShowProgress               := False;
    LPDF.ShowDialog                 := False;
    LPDF.FileName                   := LFileName;

    LReport.Export(LPDF);
  except on E:Exception do
    begin
      raise Exception.Create(E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I receive this error:
[image]

Comment: Just an idea: Give the correct name to the component you create at run time (LDataSet.Name := 'frxDBDataset1'; and use the instead of nil in the Create method.

Comment: In the report generated does the dataset use relative or absolute file name?

Comment: Hi, how good it is to cool your head with a good night's sleep. ;)
In fact, we just needed to configure the object's Name. I just put:

     LDataSet: = TfrxDBDataset.Create (nil);
     LDataset.Name: = 'frxDBDataSet1';
     LDataSet.DataSet: = Query;

There you go.
Thank you

Comment: Try 
    LReport.LoadFromFile(Format('%s\%s', [TConfig.DirFastReports, 'Catalogo_02.fr3']));
     LReport.DataSets.Clear;
    LReport.DataSets.Add(LDataSet);